# Find the range of $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (x-{\lfloor x \rfloor})$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the range of $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (x-{\lfloor x \rfloor})$

I don't know how to work with this function, and how to find the range. I tried to find the domain of its inverse, but i can't do it either.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$, hence is between zero and one. Because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ can be even or odd, the range is $(-1,1)$.

Comment: $0\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt1,$ right ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\in [0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\{x\},\  0\le \{x\}\lt 1$$
Since the fractional part is being multiplied by a factor of $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ it would just introduce the set of numbers created by multiplying by $-1$ to the well known range of the fractional part function, thereby making the range $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot

x - [x] = {x} where {x} € [0,1)
Also, [x] is always an integer.

Now for the given function we can note that ( loosely writing )
f(x) = (-1)^(integer) · {x}
Or 
f(x) = +/- {x}  depending on the value of x ( [x] being odd or even )

So, the range of f(x) = (-1,1)

This can also be used to modify the graph of fr(x) to graph f(x) (taking x-axis reflection where [x] is odd)